# How to switch back to Parent window using selenium in Java8

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I used following code for child window,

`driver.getWindowHandles().forEach(winHandle -> driver.switchTo().window(winHandle));`

How to switch to parent window??

Comment: `driver.switchTo().window("window name") `?

Comment: ```String s1 = driver.getWindowHandle(); driver.switchTO().window(s1);``` I did this but it is not working

Comment: `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
    Set<String> ids = driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> i = ids.iterator();
    String parentID = i.next(); //Parent Window
    while(i.hasNext())
    {
        String childID = i.next(); //Child Windows
        driver.switchTo().window(childID); // Iterating over child windows
    }

    driver.switchTo().window(parentID); //switching back to Parent window
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 0; // 0 for first window / tab
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(i));
```